# Maven embedder: Compiler dependency could not be resolved - No connector factories available

Tags: java, maven

I have maven projects **A** and **B**. Project **A** uses maven embedder 3.2.5 and builds with it project **B**.

```
MavenCli mavenCli = new MavenCli();
mavenCli.doMain(new String[] {"package"}, "C:\\Users\\JohnDoe\\Desktop\\abc", System.out, System.out);
```

But I get the exception:

> Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): No connector factories available

I looked into my local repository folder and there is indeed no plugin version 3.1. If I manually put it there the build is successful. But AFAIK maven automatically should download all necessary plugins. But it doesn't happen.

Comment: Please show the full pom files and which commands you have tried and which Maven version you used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding these dependencies solved my problem

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
  <artifactId>aether-connector-basic</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2.v20150114</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
  <artifactId>aether-transport-wagon</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2.v20150114</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
  <artifactId>wagon-http</artifactId>
  <version>2.8</version>
  </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
  <artifactId>wagon-provider-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

use these dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-embedder</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.resolver</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resolver-connector-basic</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.resolver</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resolver-transport-http</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

use Apache Maven Artifact Resolver instead of Aether which is archived.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy, you also need this dependency:

```
<dependency
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

I updated my application (Spring Boot 2.3, JDK8/11) to the latest Maven Embedded 3.6.3 version with the following dependencies:

```
<!-- Maven Embedder -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-embedder</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
    <artifactId>wagon-http</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
    <artifactId>aether-connector-basic</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
    <artifactId>aether-transport-wagon</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.30</version>
</dependency>
```

HTH